# PC Compatibility of MadCatz Rock Band 3 Wireless Pro-Drum and Pro-Cymbals Kit for Xbox 360

Tags: xbox-360, pc, controllers, rock-band-3

I would like to ask if there is anyone who tested Xbox 360 Rock Band 3 Pro Drums in a PC?  I'm planning to buy one.  Although I like Guitar Hero and Rock Band, I plan to use it in a Drummania-like (Konami Japanese game) setup.  There are existing drum sets for Guitar Hero and Rock Band, but if I use that, it has less drums and will result to plugging 2 sets.

Additional:
The drivers to be used are in [here](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/download/download.aspx?category=Gaming) as specified [here](http://andrewrudson.com/drummachine/troubleshoot.html).
The drum simulator used is [DTXMania](http://mainori-se.sakura.ne.jp/dtxmania/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure that if you use the Microsoft Xbox360 wireless adapter, because they use the same protocol, third-party accessories should pair as well. As far as drivers go, anything that works with the MS xb360 controller should work fine.